# Is the law of Accord and Satisfaction a very undeveloped field?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, common-law, legal-research

I have tried to find cases of [Accord and Satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_and_satisfaction#:%7E:text=The%20accord%20is%20the%20agreement,the%20parties%20to%20the%20agreement.&text=If%20the%20creditor%20breaches%20the,enjoin%20any%20action%20against%20him.) in the Jamaican Jurisdiction but there are hardly any. And the UK courts also only have a few of them. Do you know where I can get it?

Moreover, if you know about accord and satisfaction do you know if in the "Accord" part of the agreement there needs to be an offer and an acceptance from the parties involved, like in a normal contract and if yes where is the case law?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld199899/ldjudgmt/jd981216/james03.htm

Comment: The law of accord and satisfaction is very well developed in the common law, although Jamaica, because it has a fairly small population probably has a fairly modest amount of its own case law. In U.K. jurisprudence, important subsets of accord and satisfaction law have been codified into statutes, so some of the case law would be in annotations to those statutes rather than free standing, and the terminology used might not have the phrase "accord and satisfaction." But when the law is very clear in an area, new case law stagnates because there is no doubt re the law says and no need to appeal.

Comment: Thanks @ohwilleke . Is it also possible that since all of the contract law in the UK has been codified people seek remedies through the courts when there is a dispute instead of proceeding to go for a new agreement (accord) and settle the dispute through that. Thanks

Comment: @Adean No. Accord and satisfaction remains something that is practiced on a daily basis. A particularly common example of accord and satisfaction is a settlement agreement in the face of contemplated litigation or pending litigation.